# How to input m values in n times(n lines) by Ruby?

Tags: ruby, input

I have some Ruby exercises and i have problem with inputs.
I want to know how to input M values in 1 lines with space between 2 values,
and do N lines like that.
Have anyone can help me? Please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an user input then you could consider using `gets`, this way:

```
# a stores what the user introduces, in this case "a b c"
a = gets.chomp
# => "a b c"
```

If for instance you want to allow the user to enter many values, separated by a whitespace or any other, then you can use `split`, like in:

```
# in this case split without arguments takes the input as string, and divides it within every whitespace ang gives you them in an array.
a = gets.chomp.split
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Then you already have the way to get the user input for *M values in 1 lines with space between 2 values*. If you'd like to repeat this, then you could use `times`, specifying the amount of times you want this be done, i.e:

```
# This will store what the user introduces, splitted as before, and each array will be inside a "main" array.
# If for instance the input is 1 2 3 the first time, a b c the second time, then you get
a = 2.times.map do
  gets.chomp.split
end
p a
# => [["1", "2", "3"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Comment: I really thanks for your help!
But my problem are like that 
input 
N M
e_{1,1} e_{1,2} ... e_{1,N}
e_{2,1} e_{2,2} ... e_{2,N}
...
e_{M,1} e_{M,2} ... e_{M,N}